# Windows 10 not recognized by update-grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, uefi, windows-10

I have a laptop (Dell lititude e5420) with windows 10 and now kubuntu 20.10. Before kubuntu 20.10 I did use kde neon but after some problem I decided to switch to kubuntu 20.10. I download the ISO of kubuntu, put it into a USB drive, start the install but toward the end of the install I did gen an error with grub. Something like grub-install error ipossible to complete the install.

After many try a was able to boot fine kubuntu but in the grub menu I don't have the windows 10 choice. The laptop is in UEFI mode, both install in UEFI mode. Now my partition table is
NTFS 500Mb, if I mount it inside there is the Windows boot file.
NTFS 50ish Gb with the main partition of Windows 10
fat32 500Mb with EFI partition
A logic partition with inside the root directory of my kubuntu and an 8Gb of swap.
During my try to install kubuntu I try to use the first partition as EFI partition but it didn't work I think because it is a HTFS insted of fat32. By the way the first partition is marked as boot partition.
I also try
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi
sudo update-grub
but it don't recognize Windows.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? Is Windows fast start up off? Do you now have two ESP? You should only have one. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g4Zvpw4TdM/  This is the link that I get from boot-repair. Thanks.

Comment: You have new UEFI system, but Windows installed in old BIOS boot mode to 40 year old MBR(msdos) partitioning. Windows requires MBR for BIOS or requires gpt for UEFI boot. Changing from MBR to gpt will erase drive, so be sure to have good backups. You show two ESP  & grub in MBR. But sda1 is just a Windows BIOS system partition and should not have esp flag and must be NTFS. Normally you do not mix BIOS & UEFI on one drive. But just saw one user who had Windows boot loader in MBR and could boot and Ubuntu using UEFI. But you only can boot from UEFI boot menu, not from grub.

Comment: So I switch the laptop to legacy boot mode. I replace the first partition (was NTFS) to EFI. Third and fourth as before. Reinstall from zero Kubuntu and now it works fine, I can start with Windows or Kubuntu. I'll switch to GPT as soon as I'll reinstall Windows. For now I can work with this configuration. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**There must be a fatal error with GRUB.** You may need to *reinstall* Kubuntu and make sure that the EFI partition is mounted at ***/boot/efi.*** While installing, click **Something else**. Then click the EFI partition. This will be put as *efi*. Then, click the **Change...** button. This will show you a small menu, and you may be able to change the mount. **THIS MAY FORCE YOU TO FORMAT THE ESP.** If this didn't solve your problem, Windows is in Legacy BIOS. You need to convert to UEFI.

Comment: Hi, How to check if Windows is in legacy BIOS? During last install I get no error from the installer.

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is how it installs for both Windows & Ubuntu. You should normally get two boot options from UEFI boot menu one clearly UEFI:XXX where XXX is flash drive name or label. If drive is MBR(msdos) then you must have BIOS install. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#windows

Comment: To check in Kubuntu, find out if there is a folder called /sys/firmware/efi. If so, you are in UEFI. In Windows, use System Information and scroll to BIOS Mode. If it says Legacy you are in BIOS. If it says UEFI, you are using EFI. Alternatively, you can open a Command Prompt and type bcdedit. Scroll to the Windows Boot Loader section and find path. If the extension is /Windows/System32/winload.exe you are in BIOS. If it says /Windows/System32/winload.efi instead, you are in UEFI